# Is / Are: subject or object

Tags: grammar

While working on the draft of a blog post, we've come across this dilemma and, since we're all non-native speakers, we didn't come to a consensus:

> Our focus are/is projects that...

We're split pretty much 50/50 between "are" and "is".

Comment: *Our focus* comes first, and is a noun, so it is the subject. If you had *"In our focus are projects that ..."*, the subject would be *projects* because *in our focus* is a prepositional phrase.

Comment: Avoid the issue. Say: *We focus on projects that....*

Comment: Thanks! @PeterShor funny coincidence that you should answer this question that originated from a blog post about a company in the cryptocurrency space

Comment: SE has a wonderful site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com) which you might want to try.

Comment: @aparente001 Why?

Comment: @Araucaria - I don't get it.  OP talks about being part of a group of non-native speakers of English, which is what ELL SE is designed for.  If they like it, great, if they don't like it, no harm done.  Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: @aparente001 I was just interested in why you were letting them know ... Wasn't complaining ;)

Comment: @Araucaria - Oh, thanks for explaining.  "Why?" just by itself was too cryptic for me! // To answer your question, "since we're all non-native speakers" caught my eye.  It's a great site and I think it may be helpful for OP, et al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, the grammatical rule is that where verb agreement occurs (and it's much less common than it used to be in English), it only occurs with the noun phrase that is the subject of the agreeing verb. I.e, only the subject matters.

In the sentence fragment given as an example

- *[Our focus] is [projects that...]*

*Our focus* is the subject, and it's singular. So this sentence should have ***is***.

But this is an equative sentence, and equative sentences can swap NPs

- *[Projects that...] are [our focus]*

and the other NP is plural. So this sentence should have ***are***.

English verb agreement is on the way out; it's only relevant to auxiliaries with pronouns (which are mostly contracted anyway), and to third person singular present tense verbs. Other verb forms don't care whether the subject is singular or plural, and this tendency has been constant for at least 1000 years in English. So don't worry too much about it.

Comment: Could you give some examples of English verb agreement being on the way out and other verb forms that don't care whether the verb is singular or plural. As long as I have spoken English, it is only relevant to any verb in the present tense (or used as an auxiliary taken from the present tense) in the third person, as you said. But I don't get the "on the way out".

Comment: Here's a link to [the conjugation of the Old English verb _bycgan_ 'buy'](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/go.php?D1=23&T1=bycgan&H1=123). There used to be a whole lot more morphology in English than there is now.

Comment: Sorry, that does not answer the question for me. I want an example in modern English of verb agreement being on the way out. I simply cannot understand what you mean.

Comment: If you'll look at the chart, you'll see that verb agreement used to be required for verbs in all tenses (present indicative, present subjunctive, past indicative, and past subjunctive). Verbs used to agree with person and number of the subject in all those tenses, not just present tense. And the patterns were not simple, and they involved more changes in the verb than just adding a suffix or not. Probly by the time your great-great-grandchildren are learning English they won't hafta do it.

Comment: So, it is not "on the way out". It's really "gone".

Comment: Except in certain specific situations, which are frequently contracted.

Comment: Do Comp[nominal]-V-S problems ever arise?

Comment: +1 Well, that's true, but in the present tense in general really, isn't it? (sorry, am otherwise bored and reading recent grammar posts, lots of which are naturally yours. I'm not following you around!!)

Answer (score 0):

*Our focus* is singular and is the subject.